# Having a problem redirecting a form post to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a basic MVC form that allows a user to submit a zip code and after clicking submit, the user should be redirected to a new view.  My code seems to redirect to the next action successfully. However after the redirect, the controller returns back to the original action, so to the user, the page next changed at all.

Here's my View code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PricingQuote", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "rd-mailform text-center offset-top-30" }))
{
     <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="contact-zip">Zip Code</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="contact-zip" type="text" name="zip" data-constraints="@@Required">
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary offset-top-30" type="submit">GET STARTED</button>
 }
```

Here's the `PricingQuote` action in my `HomeController`.  This action redirects to the `Pricing` action in my `Pricing` controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PricingQuote(string zipCode)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Pricing", "Pricing");
}
```

Here's my `PricingController`:

```
public class PricingController : Controller
{
    // GET: Pricing
    public ActionResult Pricing()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So, after clicking <kbd>GET STARTED</kbd>, it accesses my `Home/PricingQuote` action.  This action then tries to redirect to the `Pricing/Pricing` action, which it does however, the code then seems to (incorrectly) return back to `Home/PricingQuote` and exits the action.

Any idea how I can redirect & display my `Pricing` view?

Thanks

Comment: i think your ```PricingQuote``` should be like this ```  return RedirectToAction("Pricing");```

Comment: @goalie35: Your currently posted code is correct. Therefore you need to provide more input. Except the data binding in the `ActionResult PricingQuote(string zipCode)` method of the `HomeController` will not work because of the input name in the `PricingQuote.cshtml` is "zip": change input name to `zipCode` or change the method parameter to `zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.  I was able to figure out my problem.  The name of the action I was trying to redirect to ("Pricing") was the same name as my controller ("Pricing").  As a test, I renamed my action to "PricingA" & it worked, so apparently based on this, an action cannot be the same name as the controller when attempting a "RedirectToAction", which I was unaware of (at least that's my assumption based on the results I've found).

Unfortunately, I tried googling for some add'l evidence of this, to provide with this answer, but was unable to find any.

This works:

**HomeController:**

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult PricingQuote(string zipCode)
 {
    return RedirectToAction("PricingA", "Pricing");
 }
```

**Pricing Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PricingA()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the controller in as the second parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PricingQuote(string zipCode)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Pricing", "PricingController");
}
```